# I need help understanding running time and the worst case scenario

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

My professor was trying to get me to understand running time and worst case but I'm still confused. He say look at the for loop and see how many times it iterate and I guess for this code i have below it iterate n number of times. I just not too sure though. It for the Fibonacci sequence.

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        j[i] = q;
        int A = q;
        q = u;
        u = A + q;
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < b; m++) {
        if (j[m] <= b) {
            System.out.print(j[m]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information on what exactly you are having trouble understanding? Please also give your variable proper names, `j`, `q`, `A` ect. is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The complexity of the code is **O(t)** as the loop is running `t` times. Inside loop you are calculating the next fibonacci number and storing them into an array `j[]`.

Next you are printing the content of the array, which is also simple iteration over the array.

I would suggest you to always use **relevant** and **meaningful** variable name like `n` instead of `t` and `b` while looping. Also you should name the array properly like `int fibonacci[]` instead of `int j[]`. This type of code is always self explanatory.

Comment: @jameslarge I am failing to see any inner loop. Can you point it out please?